# CanCanCan gem: load_and_authorize_resource and a controller's index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource # CanCanCan gem

  def index
    # @topics = Topic.visible_to(current_user)
  end
...
end
```

It is my understanding that `load_and_authorize_resource` loads up the necessary model instance for CRUD actions. Does that not include the `controller#index` action (where the instance variable is plural - in my case `@topics`)?

This doesn't work for me unless I uncomment the line in my `index` action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CanCanCan does load the instance variable for the index action [starting in version 1.4](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#index-action) if using a supported ORM (including ActiveRecord) and defining your abilities without blocks.

In previous versions, `load_and_authorize_resource` only loads the singular instance variable for those routes with an `:id` parameter, i.e. the CRUD actions, as you noted. It does, however, authorize for all actions, but since it doesn't load an instance variable for the index action, it only authorizes based on the model. This means that it ignores any conditions placed in the ability for that model.

Answer (score 1):

**index action**

As of 1.4 the index action will load the collection resource using accessible_by.

```
def index
  # @products automatically set to Product.accessible_by(current_ability)
end
```

via https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#load_resource